# Extract cypher relationship weights for each type (label)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I need a cypher query for extracting relationships that are labelled with VIEWED and UPDATED and display the sum of the edge weight per user.

I want to calculate a value for each user based on how many times he viewed or updated ANY document.

Example:
User a viewed document d 3 times and document e 4 times. The same user updated document f 6 times.
I want to assign points each time the user updated or viewed a document, so I need a result like the following: user: a - views: 7 - updates: 6

This is what I currently have:

```
MATCH (n:User)-[r:VIEWED|UPDATED]->(f:File) WHERE f.id IN ['some_id','another_id'] RETURN n, collect(type(r)), collect(r.weight);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query works for me:

```
MATCH (n:User)-[r1:VIEWED]->(f:File)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:User)-[r2:UPDATED]->(f:File)
WHERE f.id IN ['some_id', 'another_id']
return n, sum(r1.weight) as totalViewedWeight, sum(r2.weight) as totalUpdatedWeight
ORDER BY totalUpdatedWeight DESC, totalViewedWeight DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it, good attempt!

Either like this:

```
MATCH (n:User)-[r:VIEWED|UPDATED]->(f:File)
WHERE f.id IN ['some_id','another_id'] 
RETURN n, type(r) as type, sum(r.weight) as weight
```

or if you want one row per user:

```
MATCH (n:User)-[r:VIEWED|UPDATED]->(f:File)
WHERE f.id IN ['some_id','another_id'] 
WITH n, type(r) as type, sum(r.weight) as weight
RETURN n, collect({type:type,weight:weight})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but your query doesn't work for me because I get wrong results (e.g. 16 views instead of 54). I have no idea why...